# Avid/Pinnacle Liquid

Tags: avid, pinnacle

I have a licensed copy of Liquid on my Windows XP machine. No matter what I've tried, I can't move or reinstall it to my Windows 8.1 machine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version no.?

Comment: It's version 7.20, build 4296

Answer (score 1):

The Avid Liquid product line was [EOLed](http://www.avid.com/US/resources/liquid) in 2010 and Windows XP SP2 is the [latest](http://community.avid.com/forums/p/79375/444810.aspx#444810) Windows version supported.

At the Liquid forum, someone suggests a [method](http://forums.pinnaclesys.com/forums/thread/45770.aspx) to install Liquid 7.2 on Windows 7. See if you can use it for Windows 8.1

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this yet. Thanks for the suggestion.